# Возможно ли вообще как-то указать обьект в AddForce?

Tags: c#, unity3d

скажу конкретнее и приведу пример, мне нужно указать объект к которому я хочу применить силу
например я могу двигать его так

`object.transform.Translate (Vector3.forward * speed);`

здесь вот можно указать сам объект, тобишь "object" это и есть наш - `public GameObject object;`

Но я применяю на него силу(толкаю его), в добавок сам скрипт висит не на нем, и не должен.
Скрипт висит на камере, и мне нужно сделать так же как и в примере сверху, только с `rb.AddForce (Vector3.forward * speed);`

в данном случае, я не знаю куда его впихнуть и как указать, повторюсь МНЕ НЕ НУЖНО ВЕШАТЬ ЕГО НА САМ ОБЪЕКТ ЧТО ДВИГАЕТСЯ

погуглил но я конкретного ответа на свой вопрос не нашел

(на вопрос почему я не могу повесить скрипт на сам объект, скажу так :
управление сенсорное, и скрипт висит на канвасе, а точнее на панели, он просто чекает свайп и толкает объект)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`object.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(x,y,z);` (не оптимизировано)

Comment: жалуется на AddForce , перед ним же нужно добавить rb (rigidbody), потому что оно работает только в варианте rb.AddForce, но куда его добавить я не догнал, не в скобки, не за ними

Comment: опечатка была (исправил)

Comment: я так пробовал уже, еще вчера додумался туда вписать, оно всеравно ругается на него, я не пойму почему, что ему не так то

Comment: Можно код, для разбора

Comment: я уже разобрался , просто через vаr сделал, не важно, ваша часть кода помогла, спасибо